# Using Sequelize Build to build and validate model before saving

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a situation where I want to accept payments via Stripe but first need to validate the Form Input.

Once the form validates, in the success function I will a call for Stripe and make sure its good. If both are good, I will process payment and then SAVE the post.

I am struggling to do a validation on the Post before hand - keep in mind I don't want to save it yet.

I am using Express/Node.js with Sequelize - MySQL

```
 var post = Post.build({
    title: req.body.title,
    description: req.body.description,
  })
```

Ive tried something like this, but in my console it shows all red.

```
post.validate().error(err => {
    console.log(err)
  })
```

This solution below I found online, which does not work

```
//   if (errors) {
//     for (var prop in errors) {
//       console.log(prop.error)
//       if (errors.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
//         console.log(errors[prop])
//           console.log("Errors for field " + prop + ": ");
//             // for (var i = 0; i < errors[prop].length; i++) {
//             //          errors[prop][i];
//             // }
//     }
//   }
```

I would like to return ALL form errors at once, and then when passes, do my Stripe, then when that passes, Save Both.

Answer (score 4):

To validate fields with `sequelize` and get significant error saying where is a problem you have to use `validate: {}` property inside model definition with rule you want to check against.

Regarding to documentation:

> Model validators allow you to specify format/content/inheritance
> validations for each attribute of the model. Validations are
> automatically run on `create`, `update` and `save`. You can also call
> `validate()` to manually validate an instance.

> Validate the attributes of this instance according to validation rules
> set in the model definition.

Example:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const test = sequelize.define(
    'test',
    {
      testDate: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: DataTypes.Date,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW,
        validate: {
          isDate: true,
        },
      }
    },
    {
      freezeTableName: true,
      timestamps: false,
    }
  )
}
```

Manual validation:

```
const item = await test.build(object)
const validatedItem = await item.validate()
```

Result if do not pass validation:
[image]

More you can find here:

[https://sequelize.org/master/class/src/model.js~Model.html#instance-method-validate](https://sequelize.org/master/class/src/model.js%7EModel.html#instance-method-validate)
https://sequelize.org/master/manual/validations-and-constraints.html